SDCC problem with function return on 8051
So, I was writing some code for the 8051, and as I needed a delay, I implemented it through a timer (in mode 1):
volatile void delay_1ms(void) 
{
    TMOD = 0x01;                // Set Timer 0 to Mode 1 (16-bit timer mode)
    TH0 = 0xFC;                 // Roughly 1 ms
    TL0 = 0x2C;
    TR0 = 1;                    // Start Timer 0
    while (TF0 == 0)
    {
    } 
    TR0 = 0;                    // Stop Timer 0
    TF0 = 0;                    // Clear the Timer 0 overflow flag
}

It works fine, but as I need variable delay, I implemented a simple function that runs a 1ms timer for a certain number of times:
volatile void delay_ms(uint16_t ms)
{
    for (uint16_t i = 0; i < (ms); i++) 
    {
        delay_1ms();
    }  
    return;
}


That's where I encountered a problem that I can't solve:
The simulator throws:
eMcu::stepCpu: Error PC = 4096 PGM size = 4096
MCU stopped

when returning from the function.
Also, it seems to work when I wrap this function in a macro like this:
#define DELAY_MS(ms)               \
    do {                           \
        for (uint16_t i = 0; i < (ms); i++) { \
            delay_1ms();           \
        }                          \
    } while (0)

Some info about the setup:
I'm emulating the 8051 through SimulIDE 1.1.0 and compiling C code with SDCC 4.4.0.
As mentioned above, I tried replacing the function with a define, and it fixed the problem, but I still need to know the root problem.
I also tried some other compilers and versions of SDCC.
Minimal reproducible example:
void process(void);
void delay_1ms(void);
void delay_ms(uint16_t ms);

int main(void)
{
    process();

    return 0;
}

void delay_1ms(void) 
{
    TMOD = 0x01;
    TH0 = 0xFC;
    TL0 = 0x2C;
    TR0 = 1;
    while (TF0 == 0)
    {
    }
    TR0 = 0;
    TF0 = 0;
}

void delay_ms(uint16_t ms)
{
    for (uint16_t i = 0; i < (ms); i++) 
    {
        delay_1ms();
    }  
    return;
}

void process(void)
{
    while(1)
    {
        delay_ms(5);
    }
    
    return;
}


What does volatile void... mean in the "8051 language"?

Please add a [mre]. It seems as if your program becomes too big for the simulator. Would you mind to check that? -- The standard 8051 has just 4096 bytes ROM. The 8052 is upwards compatible and has 8192 bytes ROM. Or you configure the simulator for external ROM, which can be as big as 65536 bytes.

Forgot to remove, it was int before, and i tried to exclude compiler optimization

Just curious: What would volatile int mean then? It's still a function return type.

Well, I've tried everything at this point. I thought it might disabling compiler optimization for the return type, but as I just read, that's not how 'volatile' should be used. So, it's a mistake on my part

As for  "8051 has just 4096 bytes ROM", I also thought about it, but my program is about 1.6Kib at this point, so there should be a lot of free space left. Also macros wouldn't fix the issue if memory limitation was the case.

I would guess that your simulator is bugged. Try it on real hardware. You can also try to make all those functions static to ease inlining. 8051 was such a horrible ISA that the function call overhead was significant.

Lundin, thanks for the advice. I’ll try to test it on real hardware, and if I can't reproduce the issue, will close the question.
